# How to do Progress bar animations?

Tags: wordpress, html, css, css-transitions

I have a client that showed me another site that has some multistage progress bars like this one here: kitepharma.com/pipeline/

I have a page setup and was able to build the bars from the CSS styling but I cant for the life of me get the animations to work.

I have tried to apply a few other CSS3 animations but I cant seem to get it to work.

Can anyone provide any insight in what I'm doing wrong? I don't see any other code on their original structure that would be doing this unless its in a file that my Chrome inspector is not finding.

Here is my CSS styling that I am using:

```
.section {
display: block;
    }
 .pipe02 {
background: #CCC;
position: relative;
}
.ready {
-webkit-transition : width 2s ease;
-moz-transition: width 2s ease;
-o-transition: width 2s ease;
transition: width 2s ease;
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 2s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
transition-delay: initial;
transition-timing-function: ease;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
background: rgb(47,96,173);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(47, 96, 173) 0%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 50%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…IgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2dyYWQtdWNnZy1nZW5lcmF0ZWQpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(47, 96, 173) 0%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 50%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(47,96,173,1) 0%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 50%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(47, 96, 173) 0%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 50%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(47,96,173,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(125,185,232,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1)));
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(47, 96, 173) 0%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 50%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(47,96,173,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 50%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(47, 96, 173) 0%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 50%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(47,96,173,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 50%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(47, 96, 173) 0%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 50%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(47,96,173,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 50%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(47, 96, 173) 0%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 50%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(47,96,173,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 50%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(47, 96, 173) 0%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 50%, rgb(125, 185, 232) 100%);
background-position-x: initial;
background-position-y: initial;
background-size: initial;
background-repeat-x: initial;
background-repeat-y: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2f60ad', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 );
    }
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
    100% {background-position: -100px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
}
ul.pipelabel {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
}
ul.pipelabel li:nth-child(-n+2) {
border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
}
ul.pipelabel li {
float: left;
width: 33%;
padding: 0;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
color: #fff;
}
```

Code for Bars:

```
<section class="avia_codeblock_section avia_code_block_0">
<div class="nectar-progress-bar">
<div class="pipe02">
<div style="width: 40%;" class="ready bar-wrap">
<ul class="pipelabel">
<li>Discovery</li>
<li>Pre Test</li>
<li>PHASE 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Thank you to anyone that can give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that animation using this code. This may not be the cleanest way to make the animation but this certainly works

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    background:linear-gradient(95deg, rgba(47,96,173,1) 0%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 25%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
-webkit-animation :move 5s forwards;    

}
@-webkit-keyframes move{
    0%{ width: 400px;   }
    100%{width: 700px;
    }
}
.two{
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
-webkit-animation :moveTwo 5s forwards; 

}
@-webkit-keyframes moveTwo{
    0%{ margin-left: 400px;
        width: 400px;   }
    100%{   margin-left: 700px;
        width: 100px;
    }
}

</style>
<body>
        <div class="container">

        </div>
        <div class="two"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: With this answer I cant put text content on top of the bar like I have in the example. I was able to get an animation to work but its not working on the scroll event like the example. I am still looking for an answer that will help me to resolve this issue. Thank you for the time it helped me mak some progress.

Comment: You will have to use on-scroll animations to get the scroll thing